# building for tvOS, but linking in object file built for iOS, for architecture arm64

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, clang, tvos

I am using LexiContext framework in my tvOS app.
It works fine in simulator when I try to archive the app, I get:

```
ld: in /Users/Kashif/Dropbox/T+ve/Projects/AooForTv/lexicontext-1.2-1444206402/libLexicontext.a(Lexicontext.o), building for tvOS, but linking in object file built for iOS, for architecture arm64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any idea how to get around this.

Comment: It works in the simulator because the architecture there is x86 (or x86_64). And although the device (TV) & framework architectures are arm64 the load commands in the framework's dylib aren't TV compatible. You'll need the LexiContext framework build for TV.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. isn't there a work around? LexiContext developer not interested in building it for tvOS

Comment: no work-around… the dyld load commands are incompatible.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For others, facing similar issue; apparently there is no way around this. If you find it, please let me know.

Comment: I am also facing the exactly same issue.

Comment: @abhishek: if you end up using a different library, please let me know